# Nodemailer Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587 (errno: -61), but I specified port: 465, secure: true

Tags: node.js, google-oauth, nodemailer

I'm trying to use Nodemailer in Node.js with Google OAuth2, using port: 465, secure: true. But I'm receiving the error message below:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:587
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1137:16) {
  errno: -61,
  code: 'ESOCKET',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 587,
  command: 'CONN'
}
```

As you can see... Port 587 is coming in the error message, but it wasn't defined anywhere in my app.

In my previous configuration, I was using Nodemailer with Node.js, port: 587, secure: false, rejectUnauthorized: false. And it worked like a charm.

However, Nodemailer is defaulting to 587 for some reason. It may be my fault, but I'm declaring port: 465 with secure: true. And, according to their documentation, it only defaults to 587 if you type secure: false.

Here's my configuration:

```
async function sendEmail() {
  try {
    const REDIRECT_URI = config.redirect_uri;
    const oAuth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(config.mailClientID, 
    config.mailClientSecret, REDIRECT_URI);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials({refresh_token: config.refresh_token});
    const accessToken = await oAuth2Client.getAccessToken();

    let smtpConfigWithToken = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail',
        host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
        port: 465,
        secure: true,
        auth: {
            type: 'OAuth2',
            user: config.email,
            clientId: config.mailClientID,
            clientSecret: config.mailClientSecret,
            refreshToken: config.refresh_token,
            accessToken: accessToken
        }
    });

    let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfigWithToken);

    let HelperOptions = {
      from: '<birthmet@themetropolitanschool.com>',
      to: emailRecipients,
      bcc: '<lgranados@themetropolitanschool.com>',
      subject: "New Birthday Cake request",
      html: output
    };

    const result = transporter.sendMail(HelperOptions);
    return result;
  } catch(err) {
    return err;
  }
}
sendEmail().then(result => console.log('Email sent...', result)).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I can always go back, but I'm putting a good effort into making my apps more secure. I very much prefer not to enable "Less Secure Apps".
**Note**: the URI is also verified by Google.

As a troubleshoot step, I've run the sample code from Google and I can get the labels, as well as token.json. See this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs) for Node.js code. My app also needs access to Spreadsheets, but that part is working flawlessly (using the same token credentials).

Can you help me with a solution on this wrong port error?

Thank you in advance for taking your time reading this.

Answer (score 1):

I think **port: 465** is no longer in use for SMTP

instead use either **port: 587**, or **port: 2525**,

Answer (score 0):

Of course... It was my own fault.

I declared nodemailer.createTransport in smtpConfigWithToken and in transporter.

Looks like I've been staring at the screen for too long.

No wonder why Nodemailer went crazy with an error message that I've never seen before.

Well, at least it's documented. If you see an error -61 with Nodemailer, then please check that you don't have multiple instances of nodemailer.createTransport.

It's all working now.